# Finding the edge of the matrix using indexing

Tags: python, matrix

I am having a list of lists, which is an interpretation of a matrix
For example:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
5 6 7
```

I want to expand it to have an edge on the corners, whose values are -1

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1  1  2  3 -1
-1  2  3  4 -1
-1  5  6  7 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

I have created a new list of lists, which has +2 more rows and +2 more columns

Do people have a concise mathematical formula for a one-line if statement for determining whether an element is at the 'edge'.

I tried

```
i*j == 0
```

But it only fills in the left part of the corner.

I know this could simply be done with two if statements, but I ask this question out of the curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given inputs

```
n = 3
m = [
[1, 2, 3],
[2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7]
]
```

a simple approach would be something like

```
p = [[-1] * (n+2), *([-1] + r + [-1] for r in m), [-1] * (n+2)]
```

which gives

```
[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1,  1,  2,  3, -1],
 [-1,  2,  3,  4, -1],
 [-1,  5,  6,  7, -1],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
```

but if you want to form it from indexes (`i` and `j`), then you could use a compound boolean condition

```
[[-1 if not (i and j) or not(n+1-i and n+1-j) else m[i-1][j-1] for j in range(n+2)] for i in range(n+2)]
```

which simplifies to

```
[[-1 if not (i and j and n+1-i and n+1-j) else m[i-1][j-1] for j in range(n+2)] for i in range(n+2)]
```

but it is probably simpler to use comparisons

```
[[m[i-1][j-1] if 1 < i < n and 1 < j < n else -1 for j in range(n+2)] for i in range(n+2)]
```

or with `abs()`:

```
[[-1 if abs((n+1)/2 - i) == (n+1)/2 or abs((n+1)/2-j) == (n+1)/2 else m[i-1][j-1] for j in range(n+2)] for i in range(n+2)]
```

which works by setting the element to `-1` if the distance to the center of the matrix is equal to half the width of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I like the modulo above.  Or you could take advantage of Python's `any` operator

```
any([i==0, i==len(mat)-1, j==0, j==len(mat[0])-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure whether you want to access the 'edge' elements once you created the expanded matrix or whether you want to simplify the expansion process itself, but your question addresses the first scenario, so I'll assume that one.
Letting the list have n lists of length m (nxm matrix),

```
(i%(n-1))*(j%(m-1))==0
```

should work, as the first and last row set the first factor to 0 and the first and last column set the second to 0.